# Trying to have JSON messages deserialized to work on the Native types in django

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

The main question is: what is the process to deserialize a JSON in Django Rest Framework in order to work with it's content as native values?

Here's some specifics.

We're having trouble finding any documentation on how to do this.
We're recieving JSONs with the following structure:

```
{"idt":04F8B, 
 "ver": V10, 
 "sensores": [
    {
        "s1": 0, 
        "s2": 0, 
        "s3": 0,
        "s4": 0,
        "s5": 0, 
        "s6": 0, 
        "s7": 0, 
        "s8": 0, 
        "s9": 0, 
        "s10": 0
     }
]}
```

The data means the following:

```
1.- idt.- A unique ID for a card with a variable number of sensors
attached to it. (right now it's ten)
alpha-numeric characters
2.- ver.- The version of the card, we plan on adding functionality to
to accept two Hex figures (like an ACCI character)
right now we're only working with 1s and 0s
3.- s1, s2, (...), sN .- The sensor number and state. It can be 1, mening
there's nothing there or 0 meaning there's something there (confusing, I know)
```

The process to determine which data is relevant goes as follows:

```
1.-The proces we're trying to make is one where we can check the latest
entry for the card, 
2.- check which sensors on the JSON are different than the last reading.
3.- if a sensor has changed it's state, add it to the postgress database
and send it to the front-end.
```

some info on the database specifications:

```
1.- Each assigned sensor has an identifier in a table that is
directy connected to the readings.
2.- We're sending the same info to the Database and the front end.
3.- We're using using redis to keep a cache of all he states of assigned
sensors
4.- We need to be able to look up which sensor is changing using which
card it's in and it's identifier inside that card.
```

The proposed way to work this is by using Django Rest API. We're planning on deserializing the JSON in order to make it into Primitives we can then mold, serialize again, and finally send as endpoints.

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you worked through the django-rest tutorial on their website? I would read through the serailizer and serializer fields documentation.

You are basically going to use charfields in your serializer for idt and ver and your sensores are going to use composite fields.

Comment: Yes, but we deserialize the JSON and then ???? and then we obtain a serializable object, what do I need to ensure I get the object deserialized right?

Comment: Looking at the layout of your data, I would suggest to go ahead and translate the data without serialization and then process it in function based views then decide what to persist in the dB and what should be the composed answer. The whole point of the serializer is to produce an entity. I cannot name an entity form your description.